# jQuery addClass to ul children only

Tags: jquery, html, class, html-lists, dom-manipulation

I have this

> ```
> <ul>
>    <li class="quiddam">
>      <a href="">Lorem</a>
>      <ul>
>        <li><a href="">Ipsum</a></li>
>        <li><a href="">Dolores</a></li>
>      </ul>
>    </li>
> </ul>
> ```

If I use jquery to add a class of "brimsom" to the children of the class "quiddam" like this:

```
$(".quiddam").children().addClass("brimsom");
```

Both the a tag and ul tag children will get the class of "brimsom".

How can I add the class of "brimsom" to all children of "quiddam" that is an ul tag only?

Answer (score 4):

> Both the a tag and ul tag children will get the class of "brimsom".

That's not correct.

The following code snippet will add the class "brimson" to all elements that have the "quiddam" class, **not** the children elements.

```
$(".quiddam").addClass("brimsom");
```

Therefore:

```
<li class="quiddam brimson">
```

---

The following script would add them to all children elements:

```
$(".quiddam *").addClass("brimsom");
```

---

However, what you require is only `ul` children, which would be:

```
$(".quiddam ul").addClass("brimsom");
```

Therefore:

```
<li class="quiddam">
     <a href="">Lorem</a>
     <ul class="brimson">
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this  one `$('.quiddam ul').addClass('brimsom');`

Or this one  `$('.quiddam').find('ul').addClass('brimsom');`

Or  `$(".quiddam>ul").addClass("brimsom");`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 $(".quiddam>ul").addClass("brimsom");
```

Comment: Because answers that just solves someone code have little explanation why - are pointless, as they "feed" them with fish, not teaching how to use the rod.

Comment: As bad as this one :) as well if there is already an answer, why not to edit it to improve, why creating another one?

Comment: @MaksimsMihejevs, mate I was first one to answer. and Amit was second. You can verify by sorting it by oldest. So there was no point editing answer

Comment: My apology for not checking date! Looks like here is big competition anyway, and each answer is pretty "identical" :)

Comment: didnt work with (".quiddam>ul"). had to be ('.quiddam').find('ul')

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
 $('.quiddam ul').addClass('brimsom');
```

or

```
 $('.quiddam').find('ul').addClass('brimsom');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(".quiddam > ul").addClass("brimsom");
```

> to select the first level ul in the wrapper quiddam.

Answer (score 0):

Ha, this also works:

```
$(".quiddam").children("ul").addClass("brimsom");
```